# Finding Strings in very huge text files

Tags: linux, files, grep

I have around 100 66 Gigabyte huge "log.txt" (log1.txt,log2.txt,log3.txt and so on) files which I need to search for different Strings.

I have all 42.000 strings in a text file.

Right now, I'm using grep (`grep -F -f strings.txt log.txt`) but it takes around 50 minutes to search one log.txt.

Do you know a faster way to search all files? After searching all 100 Files, a new set of 100 files will be generated for searching.

Comment: what's the naming convention of your log files?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what do **you** mean with your *"log.txt" Files*? Files - is plural, `log.txt` is one single name. Elaborate your question, be more exact

Comment: Each file is named like log1.txt, log2.txt, log3.txt an so on.

Comment: add that to your question

Comment: this `grep -F -f strings.txt log.txt` can give pretty long output, inconvenient for visual analyzing. So, what is the main goal of matching? Should the result be saved OR it's enough to check that there are some matches within a file with just marking `log1.txt - 122 matches; log2.txt - 4000 matches`?

Comment: It is only to check if there is a match in the files. It is impossible to find all strings in 1 file.

Comment: This are not just "annoying" questions from me. I have already realized a potential working solution, but you should present the main goal in specifics.

Comment: so, would it be enough to stop searching if we have assured that at least one match found?

Answer (score 1):

Running the danger of being accused of product promotion, but if this problem is structural (as in daily time consuming) I would recommend [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

How they do it I don't know but I got 80GB files imported daily that elastic returns answers from in *miliseconds*.

Disclaimer: I am not related to that company, do not benefit in any way. Just a happy user of their products.